# Rascal Language Composition and Inheritance

Tags: sql, rascal

I am on working on SQL grammars using Rascal MPL as a Language workbench
I have noticed there are a lot of similarities between the various dialects.
How can I implement an OOP-style inheritance to facilitate code reuse
I will want to have a base SQL grammar that other dialects can inherit and override parts of.
I know that Rascal supports composition but not inheritance, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rascal by design allows for modular grammars, that can be composed. The [`extend` keyword](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Declarations/Extend/) will be the one you need, if allows you to extend an existing grammar in a different module.

Also, might be interesting to read this [comparison to OO](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/WhyRascal/CompareWithOtherParadigms/OO/).

Comment: Yes I am aware of the extend keyword and how to use it for language composition but it does have its limitation while it allows you to define additional syntax it doesn't allow you to override already defined syntax this functionality was want I am talking about.

Comment: To override already defined syntax, typically people do not extend the module that it was defined in. So this leads to small modules with language constructs, that are composed every time again using `extend` in different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Rascal grammars work like "mixins" in OO:

In one module you'd write:

```
module A

syntax Stat = "if" Exp "then" Stat "else" Stat;
```

Then in another you would write

```
module B

syntax Stat = "while" Exp "do" Stat;
```

And finally in a third module you combine the two:

```
module C

extend A;
extend B;
```

Now the syntax definitions are *fused* such that also at the recursive positions of `Stat` and `Exp` the additional alternatives are active.

So this is not like composition or inheritance, but like the kind of open recursion you get from mixins.

To be able to handle processing these trees, the functions in Rascal are also openly extensible, also for their recursive calls:

```
module A 

syntax Stat = "if" Exp "then" Stat "else" Stat;

int count(`if <Exp e> then <Stat s1> else <Stat s2>`)) = 1 + count(e) + count(s1) + count(s2)

module B

syntax Stat = "while" Exp "do" Stat;

int count(`while <Exp e> do <Stat s1>`)) = 1 + count(e) + count(s1)

module C

extend A;
extend B;
```

Here after the `extend` the recursive calls for `count` will deal with the new alternatives of `count` (i.e. the case for the while loop from the other module).

If you don't use dynamic dispatch (overloading) like this, but hide the processing inside of function bodies (visits and switches, or nested if-then-elses) then your language processor is not composable or extensible.

Comment: Will this work if matching against AST(ADT) or strictly with concrete pattern?

Comment: it works with any pattern. even numbers:`int f(0) = 1; default int f(int n) = n * f(n-1);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was thinking about a way to simulate override of syntax, what about defining a new syntax for the `while` statement in module C and then filter the pattern of the extended `while` statement during parsing of language C, how does this sound?